# Any way to pause a task and then restart within a pipe

Tags: command-line, filesystem, btrfs, pipe

I use a command like
`btrfs restore -iv /dev/sdc1 /RESTORED`

estimated time of running it is few days

In every hour of running I see a lot of prompts like:

```
We seem to be looping a lot on /path/to/some/file, do you want to keep going on?
(y/N/a)
```

I'd like to say `N` to all remaining prompts, but there is no such option
(according to `man btrfs-restore` and `btrfs` )

I think I need this:
`yes N | btrfs restore -iv /dev/sdc1 /RESTORED` (which will start restore again)

Is any way to pause a running task (not cancel) and then resume within a pipe
like

`ctrl+Z` + `$ yes N | fg`

(the above return `fg no job control`). fg here is only to show what I mean.

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think it is possible to redirect standard input on the fly. One work around could be to use `xdotool` or `xvkbd` to simulate repeatedly pressing N. A script doing that could be launched with a shortcut key when the command is running and starts to ask confirmations.

Comment: This is really a job for `expect`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a **workaround** like this:

simply I generated a list of `N` (for example by `yes N`)

copied that and paste into running task

It is of course limited, so in my case, I've copied 10K lines of N.

the list must be with a single `N` per line.